# MySQL InnoDB deadlock problem with two same queries (different parameters)

Tags: mysql, transactions, innodb, deadlock, database-deadlocks

I have the following table

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `task` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `job_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL COMMENT 'The id of the related job',
  `server_id` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'job/task owner',
  `jobtype_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `node_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL COMMENT 'The id of the user currently executing this task',
  `status` enum('QUEUED','EXECUTING','COMPLETED','CANCELED','TERMINATED','PAUSED','FAILED') NOT NULL COMMENT 'Current status of the task',
  `last_updated` int(11) NOT NULL COMMENT 'When was the last status change of this task. Used in requeueing hung tasks',
  `data_in` blob NOT NULL COMMENT 'An input data to the task. Sets when the task is created.',
  `data_out` blob NOT NULL COMMENT 'An output data of the task. Sets upon task completion. Can be absent.',
  `speed` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `time_spent` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `has_data_out` tinyint(1) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Shows if the task has any output data. Serves caching purposes. Used by Summarizers to quickly find out what tasks of the job yielded data.',
  `comment` varchar(200) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `fk_task_job_id` (`job_id`),
  KEY `index_has_data_out` (`has_data_out`),
  KEY `index_last_updated` (`last_updated`),
  KEY `index_status` (`status`),
  KEY `fk_task_userid` (`node_id`),
  KEY `jobtype_id` (`jobtype_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='This table holds all subjobs - tasks' AUTO_INCREMENT=1081595 ;

--
-- Constraints for dumped tables
--

--
-- Constraints for table `task`
--
ALTER TABLE `task`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `task_ibfk_5` FOREIGN KEY (`job_id`) REFERENCES `job` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  ADD CONSTRAINT `task_ibfk_7` FOREIGN KEY (`jobtype_id`) REFERENCES `jobtype` (`id`),
  ADD CONSTRAINT `task_ibfk_8` FOREIGN KEY (`node_id`) REFERENCES `node` (`id`);
```

And the following deadlock problem:

```
------------------------
LATEST DETECTED DEADLOCK
------------------------
110831 14:23:56
*** (1) TRANSACTION:
TRANSACTION 102B4D2, ACTIVE 0 sec, OS thread id 5480
mysql tables in use 2, locked 1
LOCK WAIT 7 lock struct(s), heap size 1248, 4 row lock(s), undo log entries 3
MySQL thread id 74315, query id 2364347 192.168.1.120 usr_sl3 Sending data
select `usr_sl3`.`task`.`id` from `usr_sl3`.`task` where (`usr_sl3`.`task`.`node_id` = 103 and `usr_sl3`.`task`.`status` = 'EXECUTING') for update
*** (1) WAITING FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
RECORD LOCKS space id 38 page no 2303 n bits 576 index `index_status` of table `usr_sl3`.`task` trx id 102B4D2 lock_mode X locks rec but not gap waiting
Record lock, heap no 471 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 2; compact format; info bits 32
0: len 1; hex 02; asc  ;;
1: len 4; hex 00107dac; asc   } ;;

*** (2) TRANSACTION:
TRANSACTION 102B4D3, ACTIVE 0 sec, OS thread id 5692 starting index read, thread declared inside InnoDB 500
mysql tables in use 2, locked 1
7 lock struct(s), heap size 1248, 4 row lock(s), undo log entries 3
MySQL thread id 74354, query id 2364348 192.168.1.120 usr_sl3 Sending data
select `usr_sl3`.`task`.`id` from `usr_sl3`.`task` where (`usr_sl3`.`task`.`node_id` = 95 and `usr_sl3`.`task`.`status` = 'EXECUTING') for update
*** (2) HOLDS THE LOCK(S):
RECORD LOCKS space id 38 page no 2303 n bits 576 index `index_status` of table `usr_sl3`.`task` trx id 102B4D3 lock_mode X locks rec but not gap
Record lock, heap no 471 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 2; compact format; info bits 32
0: len 1; hex 02; asc  ;;
1: len 4; hex 00107dac; asc   } ;;

*** (2) WAITING FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
RECORD LOCKS space id 38 page no 2303 n bits 576 index `index_status` of table `usr_sl3`.`task` trx id 102B4D3 lock_mode X locks rec but not gap waiting
Record lock, heap no 481 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 2; compact format; info bits 32
0: len 1; hex 02; asc  ;;
1: len 4; hex 00107dab; asc   } ;;

*** WE ROLL BACK TRANSACTION (2)
```

Can you please help me to understand the mechanism of this deadlock?

Those two queries are issued from different threads. Each thread has it's own node_id in query. No two queries have same node_id.

I suspect, that I can solve the situation by creating a compound index on fields (node_id, status), but this isn't a good solution, I think. I need to understand the nature of the problem.

These deadlocks on the same query occure periodically, not once or twice.

EXPLAIN on affected queries gives interesting results:

```
id  select_type     table   type    possible_keys   key     key_len     ref     rows    Extra
1   SIMPLE  task    index_merge     index_status,fk_task_userid     index_status,fk_task_userid     1,4     NULL    1   Using intersect(index_status,fk_task_userid); Using where; Using index
```

MySQL version is 5.5.

Also, at the moment of the deadlock, tables contain no rows matching condition of the affected query (e.g. select `usr_sl3`.`task`.`id` from `usr_sl3`.`task` where (`usr_sl3`.`task`.`node_id` = 95 and `usr_sl3`.`task`.`status` = 'EXECUTING') for update
yields no rows at all).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query uses the index_status index instead of fk_task_userid (the index on node_id). This is the reason it locks records with other node_ids.

You can run explain on your query to see how much records are actually locked (in rows examined) vs how much of them you need to lock (rows returned)

> I suspect, that I can solve the situation by creating a compound index on fields (node_id, status), but this isn't a good solution, I think. I need to understand the nature of the problem.

Why? I feel your indexes are not optimal anyway... Create index on node_id,status, it should resolve the problem

Comment: Added EXPLAIN result into the question. Query uses index_merge or index intersection in this query.

Comment: I performed a test using two mysql clients and when index_merge is used all rows matching the first index are locked, so the compound index IS needed to ensure only the matched rows are locked.